# TextBox time hour,min Textbox minutes Add to DataGrid

Tags: c#

I have 2 textboxes one the user enters a time 20:15 and another textbox that has minutes this is calculated from other boxes 225:00. A third textbox that has the number of conatines. Out put should be 20:15 6 containers 225:00 minutes apart.     20:15:00,0:00:00,3:45:00,7:30:00,11:15:00,15:00:00. I get a return of 20:15:00,20:15:00,20:15:00,20:15:00,20:15:00,20:15:00.                                  .

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: How do i get it to increment correctly?

Comment: why not write a simpel console app with hard coded strings in it and make sure your assumptions of how all those Convert and DateTime functions work are correct

Comment: it is impossible to understand what you are trying to do and what your issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens when you do this

```
var start_time = "10.15";
var minutes_apart = "225"; // or whatever you expect the string to be
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(start_time);
int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(minutes_apart);
dt = dt.AddMinutes(minutes_apart);
```

in a separate console app. Does it do what you expect?

Comment: I get the same result. I will post the whole code above

Comment: see my comment about writing a simple console app

Comment: wanting a winform the time containers and min always change

Comment: i know what you want, if you are stuck try doing someting simple first, then build on it.

Comment: OR - step through the code with a debugger, see when you first get something unexpected - reminder, nobody trying to help you  has any idea what you are trying to do or what your problem is , yr question is not clear at all

Comment: I am new to C# I have textboxs and comboboxs to do the math. The math calculation is      200 (textbox1) / 34  (combobox1)  = 5.8 (textbox4).......then 1350 min (combox2 / 5.8 (textbox4) = 232 min (textbox5)... then take (textbox6) .. time entered 20:15 then add the min Textbox5 ..to textbox6 code above. Thanks for staying in there .pm100

Comment: pm 100, i have been stuck on this for 5 days it the last part of the program. It's simple for some but being a shade tree coder im stumped.

Comment: i keep telling you what to do. Isolate a simple case of what you are trying to do. Or try to clearly explain it to me. I have no idea what your problem is

Comment: i want to add whatever minutes(textbox5) and time(textbox6) together and loop through number in textbox4.

Comment: did you actualy try doing what I suggest in this answer. Did you try stepping through with a debugger and look at all the variabgles at each step to see if you get what you expect?

Comment: Thanks Got it going